# Organizing grep with linebreaks

Tags: linux, bash, grep, nmap

How can I add linebreaks between my egrep?

```
# nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | egrep 'MAC|report'
```

I would like to add a linebreak after each of the two lines. What is the most efficient shorthand?

Essentially I'd like the result to be output like so:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.7
MAC Address: C4:42:02:xx:xx:xx (Samsung Electronics Co.)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.8
MAC Address: 04:F1:3E:xx:xx:xx (Apple)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
MAC Address: 70:18:8B:xx:xx:xx (Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to add a linebreak after each of the two lines.

The solution to this literal problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182207). In your case:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | egrep 'MAC|report' | sed '0~2 s/$/\n/g'
```

However I've seen `nmap` outputs where some reports miss their `MAC` line, so (instead of blindly counting lines) you'd rather want a newline before every `Nmap`, unless it's in the very first line:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | egrep 'MAC|report' | sed '1! s/^Nmap/\nNmap/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with

```
nmap -sP 192.168.10/24 | egrep 'MAC|report|Host is up' | sed  '/Host is/c\\r'
```

This searches for the additional string "Host is up" and then replaces it with a carriage return.

This results in the following output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1

MAC Address: 00:0E:C6:C7:93:38 (Asix Electronics)
Nmap scan report for  (192.168.1.254)

MAC Address: 1C:C1:DE:80:53:55 (Hewlett Packard)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.250
```

Comment: This puts the space within each entry of the two lines where it should be connected instead of spaced

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  I've updated my answe with the output I get.  Can you update yours with the output you want ?

Comment: I wonder if you are using a different OS and are running into a CR/LF difference - if thats all the problem is, you can pipe your output to "todos" or equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I simply mean the linebreak should follow the 'MAC Address' line instead of the 'Nmap scan report' line